# Explicit cast to defined type throws `InvalidCastException`

Tags: c#, casting

I have some custom wrapper types defined with an explicit cast operation:

```
private class A
{
    private readonly int _value;

    public A(int value)
    {
        _value = value;
    }

    public int Value { get { return _value; } }
}

private class B
{
    private readonly int _value;

    private B(int value)
    {
        _value = value;
    }

    public int Value { get { return _value; } }

    public static explicit operator B(A value)
    {
        return new B(value.Value);
    }
}
```

The following works just fine:

```
B n = (B)new A(5);
```

This does not:

```
B n = (B)(object)new A(5);

// Throws System.InvalidCastException:
// Unable to cast object of type 'A' to type 'B'
```

...what's going on here?
I'm constrained to have the cast to `object` first - the actual cast is being performed elsewhere in generic library code (so it's of the form `return (TOutput)(object)input;`, and `dynamic` is not an option)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason the first code snippet works is that what you see is *not* a "straight" cast: it is an invocation of an explicit conversion operator. This operation is well-defined, and works exactly the way it is coded: a brand-new object `B` is constructed from `A`'s value. C# has enough information to determine that the explicit operator is to be invoked, because `new A(5)` type matches the type of `operator B(A value)` parameter.

Once you add a cast to `object`, however, the compiler does a true cast. C# no longer has an applicable user-defined conversion operator, so it does the type check, determines that `A` is not convertible to `B`, and throws an exception.

There is a way to make it work without `dynamic` by building and compiling a dynamic lambda, like this:

```
private static B ConvertFromObject(object a) {
    if (a == null) return null;
    var p = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object));
    var c1 = Expression.Convert(p, a.GetType());
    var c2 = Expression.Convert(c1, typeof(B));
    var e = (Func<object,B>)Expression.Lambda(c2, p).Compile();
    return e(a);
}
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/b2Vmj2)

You could cache compiled lambdas by `a`'s runtime type to save on the costs of compiling a new expression each time you run the method.

Comment: I'm sorry, it turns out I'm still a bit confused by this.  _Why_ does C# no longer have the explicit conversion operator?  What makes it go away?  I'd appreciate having some reference for this...

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse With that conversion operator defined, C# knows how to make a conversion from `A` to `B`, but not from `object` to `B`. By adding a cast from `A` to `object` you tell the compiler that you want it to "forget" the static type of object `new A(5)`, and treat it as an object with static type `System.Object`, because the static type of expression `(object)new A(5)` is `object`, not `A`.